# with emacs,I can't export source code in org file to html in highlight mode

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I have taken htmlize in use, here is the configuration

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
         "~/.emacs.d/plugins/")
(require 'htmlize)
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)   
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts nil)
```

with this configuation, After I export the org file below: I get the output like the picture at the bottom of this page.

```
#+STYLE: <style> pre.src { background-color:#1e3436; color: #eeeeec;}</style>
*tst code
#+BEGIN_SRC c
 extern struct list_head llc_sap_list;
  int a = 0;
#+END_SRC
#+begin_src c 
 #define LLC_DEST_INVALID         0      /* Invalid LLC PDU type */
 #define LLC_DEST_SAP             1      /* Type 1 goes here */
 #define LLC_DEST_CONN            2      /* Type 2 goes here */


 extern spinlock_t llc_sap_list_lock;

 extern int llc_rcv(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev,
        struct packet_type *pt, struct net_device *orig_dev);

 extern int llc_mac_hdr_init(struct sk_buff *skb,
             const unsigned char *sa, const unsigned char *da);

 extern void llc_add_pack(int type, void (*handler)(struct llc_sap *sap,
                        struct sk_buff *skb));
 extern void llc_remove_pack(int type);

 extern void llc_set_station_handler(void (*handler)(struct sk_buff *skb));

 extern struct llc_sap *llc_sap_open(unsigned char lsap,
                 int (*rcv)(struct sk_buff *skb,
                        struct net_device *dev,
                        struct packet_type *pt,
                        struct net_device *orig_dev));
 static inline void llc_sap_hold(struct llc_sap *sap)
 {
     atomic_inc(&sap->refcnt);
 }

 extern void llc_sap_close(struct llc_sap *sap);

#+end_src
```

the output html, the color of the code is all in gray.
I can't upload it, but this problem really blocked me, in this whole night. thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Are you by chance exporting it while running non-GUI version of Emacs? Because in that case the fontification level is minimal and never coloured.

Comment: What version of Org-Mode are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting this?

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

I think you want the opposite (which is the default).  Try setting it to `nil` and `htmlize` should kick in.

In fact, I don't think you even need the

```
(require 'htmlize)
```

I have it installed from ELPA, so maybe that set up the autoload, but I don't have any reference to `htmlize` in my `.emacs` and it "just works."

Comment: In fact, before I ask help from google and get the needs of htmlize, I didn't add anthing in my .emacs, and the highlight doesn't work so I goto google for a help. Then I add these configurations in .emacs.